# Asymptotic probability distribution of product of Matrices

Tags: probability-distributions, infinite-product, central-limit-theorem, random-matrices, lyapunov-functions

Suppose that $$L=\prod \limits_{i=1}^n M_i,$$
where $M_i$ are $2\times2$ matrices of the form
$$M_i=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1\exp(j\phi_{1,i}) & \alpha_2\exp(j\phi_{2,i}) \\
\alpha_2\exp(j\phi_{1,i}) & \alpha_1\exp(j\phi_{2,i})
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 \\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
\exp(j\phi_{1,i}) & 0 \\
0 &\exp(j\phi_{2,i})
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\phi_{1,i}$ and $\phi_{2,i}$ are chosen i.i.d. with Uniform distribution over $[0,2\pi]$ and
\begin{align*}
D=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 \\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
is a Unitary Matrix.

What can we say about the distribution of $L$, when $n \rightarrow \infty$? Can a variant of Central Limit Theorem be applied here? Or at least an upper bound on the maximum probability of entries of $L$?

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: Yes. Should I use different symbol for that?

Comment: Not necessarily, just that since $i$ is also used, I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Do $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ depend on $i$?

Comment: I can say that let's call them $\phi_{1,i}$ and $\phi_{2,i}$, where they are chosen i.i.d with uniform distribution. I will modify it above. Thanks.

Comment: I think that your upper right $\phi$ changed from index $2$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified it.

Comment: useful reference: https://www.worldcat.org/title/products-of-random-matrices-in-statistical-physics/oclc/27812809

Comment: Thanks. One question: The Lyapunov Exponent is related to the value to which product of random matrices will converge, right? Here, I'm interested actually to the maximum probability value of for example $L_{1,1}$, and not which value it converges to.